# Annotations not showing with version 2.0.4

Tags: android, pdf, pdfbox

Im using ported pdfbox lib for android **by TomRoush PdfBox-Android** to annotate and render pdf files.
With current latest version 2.0.4, I can easily add annotations and I can also view them in Acrobat Reader (ONLY).
But they are not showing in different viewers. (Including pdfbox renderer)

I have seen some advices to use ***constructAppearances(document)***; to make sure annotation can be shown in all viewers. But it is not part of 2.0.4 codebase yet.

Any advice, how can I achieve that with 2.0.4 codebase ?

Thanks a lot man and GJ

Comment: You need to add the code behind from `constructAppearances` (lots of "handlers") from the desktop project to the codebase. Alternatively, you need to add the annotation content yourself as an extra step outside of PDFBox. There are many different annotations so this is huge. Use PDFDebugger of the desktop project to see whether your annotation is supported (a few are not, e.g. the ones with stamps).

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. I tried it and it seems I need the ported library to be of version 2.0.16 to make it work.

Comment: The desktop version is at 2.0.24.